# Changing return type of an Observable with map

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been researching how to change the return type of an Observable.

I'm using Angular 5.

Here's an example :

```
public getButterfly(): Observable<Butterfly[]> {
    return http.get<Larva[]>('url').pipe(
        map( larva => new Butterfly(larva.dna))
    );
}
```

This code cause an ERROR because for the compiler expect the larva object to be a Butterfly because of the return value and throw an error:

"error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Butterfly[]'."

It seems that typescript doesn't allow type changes inside the observable, but if you know a way, i'm all ears.

Thank you for taking an interest in my question.

Comment: Try to remove <Larva>

Comment: Doesn't change the outcome, typescript assume the type of the observable input from the return type of the function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type definitions of `map` operator are as follows:

```
export declare function map<T, R>(
  project: (value: T, index: number
) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R>;
```

As you can see, you can set generic types in the `map` operator call. In your example, the `T` value is the Butterfly, and the `R` value is the Larva.

```
public getButterfly(): Observable<Butterfly[]> {
  return http.get<Larva[]>('url').pipe(
    map<Larva, Butterfly>(larva => new Butterfly(larva.dna))
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not a good practice in general, it is telling the compiler what something is and it might be something else. My answer explains the real root of the problem. Technically I want to downvote this - but I don't want you to delete it (because it's valuable to understand why this isn't correct) so I'm not doing so :-) Nothing personal :)

Comment: Great comment. I think @pierre should change the accepted answer :) I think I got thrown off by the singular name in the map operator callback. Array map inside the RxJS map can get a bit confusing.

Answer (score 32):

I think the accepted answer has masked a bigger problem, and perhaps a confusion in your understanding of what `map` actually does in rxjs.

In 'normal' Javascript - the `map()` function operates **directly on an array** and runs a function for every item in the array. eg. `[1,2,3].map(x => x + 1)`. You **immediately** get back a full array of the same length as the original - with the transformed items.

In `rxjs` it is a completely different function that's part of rxjs and only has the same name as Array's `map` (go find the sourcecode if you dare!).

The actual function you pass to the rxjs `map()` still takes a single value and returns a single value (so it looks very much like the pure javascript map) but instead of operating on an array it operates on a single value **in a stream**.

Ok so you already know RXJS is about streams! And you have a stream of larvae right! *(I don't know if this is terrifying or adorable!)*

Well you actually don't. **With `http.get` you do have a stream, but it only contains ONE value and that ONE value is the entire response from your http call whatever it may be**.

By the look of it you're returning an array of Larva objects from the `get` call, but as far as RXJS is concerned this is a stream of ONLY ONE item.

This is your original code (annotated):

```
  public getButterfly(): Observable<Butterfly[]> {
   return http.get<Larva[]>('url').pipe(
       map( larva => {

           // We are now inside the RXJS 'map' function, NOT a Javascript map
           // here larva is an ARRAY (assuming your HTTP call actually returns an array)
           // So if you execute larva.dna you'll get 'undefined' 
           // (because dna is not a property on a javascript array!)
           // So you will return a butterfly OBJECT, but initialized with 'undefined' DNA. Scary!

           return new Butterfly(larva.dna);
       })
   );
}
```

So what I think you actually want is this:

```
public getButterflies() {
    return http.get<Larva[]>('url').pipe(
        map( larvae => larvae.map(larva => new Butterfly(larva.dna)))
    );
}
```

If that doesn't immediately make sense here's what's happening:

- You get a array back from the http call (larvae - which you're telling typescript is typed as Larva[])
- We then run the standard javascript `map` function on that array for EACH item and create a butterfly for each. You then return that new butterfly array as a replacement item in the stream.
- Remember you have a stream. But it is a stream of one item. And each item is an array.
- Note: The output type doesn't need to be specified and is automatically `Butterfly[]`

By sticking in `<Larva, Butterfly>` you're just **telling** the compiler that's what it is so you don't get compile time errors. You're never **changing** anything.

PS. Sometimes I like to specify output type, when it's simple - in order to show mistakes inside the 'pipe'. I'll do this if I have several code paths, each of which must return the same. By constraining the output type it reveals more errors.

Tip: Use `tap(x => console.log('Message', x)` in the pipe to write to the console what you have at each stage like this:

```
public getButterflies() {
    return http.get<Larva[]>('url').pipe(
        tap( x => console.log('Before map', x) ),
        map( larvae => larvae.map(larva => new Butterfly(larva.dna)),
        tap( x => console.log('After map', x) )
    ));
}
```

Why is it called tap? Because pipes have taps! And a (regular water) tap lets you see what's inside a (regular water) pipe :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the similar scenario and requirement, and just found that `concatAll` can turn Larvae[] into 'stream' of individual Larvae, so do you think if it's good to do `concatAll(), map(larvae => new Butterfly(larva.dna))` in pipe() rather than a nested map?

Comment: @JunlongWang that would only make sense if you really needed to do something asynchronous with all those butterflies - like make some additional server call (and wait for the response) for each before you returned an instance. If the operation is just a simple non asynchronous call (like `new Butterfly()` then you wouldn't gain anything from it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Simon, I see what you mean now and agree. I was struggling to understand operators and now I feel much clearer.

Comment: When I do this I get "map does not exist on Observable<Larva[]>"

Comment: @PrimeByDesign the iPhone app seems to be broken and I can’t see my actual answer. 1) make sure to import map with ‘import { map } from ‘rxjs/operators’. 2) you may need to convert to the pipe syntax. ‘larvae.pipe(map(lava => { return ...; }))’

Comment: Ah it turned out I wasn't using map from the library I thought I was. I'd used ctrl + . In VSCode to import the appropriate library but it has imported the wrong one. Turns out lodash also has an implementation of Map.which isn't what I thought I was using.